# Orchard CMS: How to implement custom field indexing?

Tags: orchardcms

I have HtmlBlock field and I want to add this field to Orchard CMS index.

Is there some stuff I have to implement to add field in index, like OnIndexing method for custom part indexing described here: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/255183

Comment: OnIndexing<T> is the method you need, yes :) Add it to your content handler

Comment: I have no content handler for field: http://htmlblocks.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest it is just a field.

Comment: Sorry, I totally thought you had a part... my bad ^^ sorry, never made a custom part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable custom fields indexing you need to describe fields in FieldDriver.

```
protected override void Describe(DescribeMembersContext context)
{
    context
        .Member(null, typeof(string), T("HTML"), T("The HTML value of the field."))
        .Enumerate<HtmlBlockField>(() => field => new[] { field.HTML });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after I actually read your question instead of just writing a dumbass comment repeating random words you had written, fields in Orchard automagically get that "include in index" added to them. This is done in the Indexing module in Settings/EditorEvents.cs. It should then go ahead and index your field. Make sure you enable Indexing :)

I did just test it on my super quickly made field and it did appear to work. But I wouldn't say I'm 100% sure ^_^

Comment: What is difference between your quickly made field and my filed htmlblocks.codeplex.com/SourceControl? Am I need to add something special to get filed in index? My field does not apear on Index settings page /Admin/Settings/Search